# Keep from creating duplicate entry above zero

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

Would it be possible to create a database-level restriction to prevent creating a row that has a column `x INT` with a value that already exists and is above 0?

Is there a way to use `CONSTRAINT` for this purpose?

Comment: NULL might be an option I guess, what did you have in mind?

Comment: exactly what you answered yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    myfield INT,
    CONSTRAINT check_myfield UNIQUE ( myfield )
);
```

Now, the column `myfield` might be NULL. So when we do the following, there will be a total of 0 errors.

```
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( '', '1' );
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( '', '0' );
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( '', '5' );
INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( '', '7' );
etc, you get the point...
```

Each and every row has a unique value in the column `myfield`, but there is still the possibility to create rows where the value in this particular column is `NULL` which is almost exactly what I wanted. I wanted all values above 0 unique, this is all above `NULL`. The beauty of this solution is that it feels more 'professional', no unnecessary logic.

Comment: If you want to disallow negative values, make that `myfield INT UNSIGNED`

Comment: That would be a helpfull contribution.